# Unable to add folders to Dock

Tags: dock

Strangely, all folders (only `Downloads` in my case) have vanished form my dock. A reboot did not help.
I can still drag apps onto it, but not directories. 
How can I find out what the problem is and maybe fix it? Is there some configuration `.plist` to which I could manually add stuff?

The system is 10.12.3 on an MBP 9,2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restored `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` and `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.extra.plist` from Time Machine and `killall`ed `Dock` and now it works. I suspect the first file is the only relevant one since it contains an entry for the directory.